# Compare 2 different columns in 2 different Excel Files

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

This is a bit different than the others.  I'm trying to compare 2 different inventory sheets, comparing serial numbers of equipment from 2 different reports.  I have File A which has 4 worksheets in it.  Worksheet 4 has columns A-AM and I'm looking at column G.  File B has 1 worksheet, columns A-AG and I'm looking at column E.

I'm trying to confirm the values in File 1, worksheet 4, column G matches the values in File 2, worksheet 1, column E.  The data isn't in the same order so I'm having an issue finding a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a separate worksheet and paste each column into it and sort both columns? I remember there being another way but I do not remember, I will update this If I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula to return serial numbers In File A worksheet 4 that are matched in the File B worksheet 2:

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH('[FileA.xlsx]Worksheet 4'!G1,'[FileB.xlsx]Worksheet 1'!$E:$E,0)),"",'[FileA.xlsx]Worksheet 4'!G1)

Identified are the two Files with their relevant columns that contain the data to be compared.
Create a new check column in your working spreadsheet in File A.
Add the formula and drag down to bottom.

If you want to use a true false statement then substitute as:

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH('[FileA.xlsx]Worksheet 4'!G1,'[FileB.xlsx]Worksheet 1'!$E:$E,0)),FALSE,TRUE)

**Edit**
If you require for results on File B against File A add check column on File B and use this Formula

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH('[FileB.xlsx]Worksheet 1'!E1,'[FileA.xlsx]Worksheet 4'!$G:$G,0)),"",'[FileB.xlsx]Worksheet 1'!E1)

Explanation how the formula works

Checking Cell A1 in File 1 against column A in File 2

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH('[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1,'[File2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0)),"",'[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1)

The Match cell on File1 Sheet1 A1 is checked against array as column A on File2 Sheet1 the match type 0 looks for exact match (Note match type 0 not case sensitive) if not found returns error as #N/A.
The iserror command is used for the If statement logical test, returning value if true (on error) as blank text field. If a match is found the iserror is thus false and the if statement returns "value if false" as the value of Cell A1 in File 1.